# Cascade kendo dropdownlists in dhtmlx lightbox in MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, dhtmlx

I have a problem with two cascade kendo dropdownlists placed in DHTMLX lightbox. I can't filter second list with ajax call because my script can't get value from the first list. I noticed that DHTMLX lightbox is based on iframe, and this is an issue but how can resolve this problem.

Here is my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Checklist[i].IDSerwisu)
     .OptionLabel(" ")
     .DataTextField("Text")
     .DataValueField("Value")
     .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
     .DataSource(source => {
        source.Read(read => {
             read.Action("GetServices", "Services");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
     })
)

<br />
Pracownik serwisu:
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m =>   
    m.Checklist[i].IDPracownikaSerwisu)
        .OptionLabel(" ")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
        .DataSource(source => {
             source.Read(read =>{
                read.Action(
                    "GetContractorsEmployees",  
                    "Services"
             ).Data("filterServices("+i+")");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
   })
   .CascadeFrom("Checklist_"+i+"__IDSerwisu")
)
```

And here is my script for cascading lists:

```
function filterServices(i) {

    var ids = $("#Checklist_" + i + "__IDSerwisu").val();

    return { ID: ids }
}
```

My filtering server-side function always reciving null as ID:

```
 public JsonResult GetContractorsEmployees(string text,int? ID) {
     ID = ID == null ? 0 : ID;
     List<SpisOsobyKontaktoweModel> list = _repositorySpisSerwis.GetEmployees((int)ID);

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {
         list = list.Where(item => (item.Imie + " " + item.Nazwisko).ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())).ToList();
     }

     return Json(list.Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e.Imie + " " + e.Nazwisko, Value = e.ID_Osoby.ToString() }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Verify that the CascadeFrom value is defined correctly. Use Html.IdFor to be sure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by adding hidden input for first dropdownlist value, because I needed to avoid using jquery method to get the dropdownlist value. To populate inputs I needed to use dropdownlist select event.

```
    function onSelect(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
    var i = this._optionID.split("_")[1];
    document.getElementById("ids" + i).value = dataItem.Value;
}
```

After that I could access first value in filter function:

```
function filterServices(i) {
    return { ID: document.getElementById("ids" + i).value }
}
```